# ASP.NET - Deleting IdentityUser throw SqliteException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

I am using scaffolded DeletePersonalData, and when trying to delete user, the program throw exception:

```
SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(int rc, sqlite3 db)
```

Code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }

            RequirePassword = await _userManager.HasPasswordAsync(user);
            if (RequirePassword)
            {
                if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, Input.Password))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Incorrect password.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            var result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user); // This throw exception
            var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected error occurred deleting user.");
            }

            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

            _logger.LogInformation("User with ID '{UserId}' deleted themselves.", userId);

            return Redirect("~/");
        }
```

Call stack:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable<ModificationCommandBatch> commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable<ModificationCommandBatch> commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable<ModificationCommandBatch> commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList<IUpdateEntry> entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore<TUser, TRole, TContext, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserRole, TUserLogin, TUserToken, TRoleClaim>.DeleteAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
WebApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage.DeletePersonalDataModel.OnPostAsync() in DeletePersonalData.cshtml.cs
```

This is code created by VisualStudio, and I assume this should work but somehow, it does not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any other tables that have the User ID as a foreign key? If so, it may not be allowing you to delete the user because there are other tables that have columns that require that user to exist. Make sure all other tables that reference that User ID have those columns removed before you remove the Identity User.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your entity and its navigation configuration in context?

Comment: @kasprdev you were right. It turns out, that I had a table that have UserId as FK. By naming property 'UserId', it creates that FK automatically. I manually go to migration folder and delete that unwanted relation, and now everything works. Thank you!